# Git integration from inside virtual host

Tags: git, phpstorm

My current development environment is a Windows host with an Ubuntu guest (using Vagrant).  I currently use the PHPStorm Git integration to manage my repo.  I've installed Git in Windows, and this works well 99% of the time.

I've run into two errors with this setup:  line endings and permissions.  While line endings are simple enough to deal with, managing Linux permissions from Windows isn't simple (to make these changes I ssh into the guest OS).

I would like to have PHPStorm's Git integration call git from the guest OS instead of Windows.  Is this possible?

Comment: I can't figure out how to configure PHPStorm to run Git from inside the guest machine.

Comment: PHP-Storm does not use Git from the guest. You have to install Git at your Windows host and Storm will find and execute it.

Comment: @Dietmar, that's how I currently have it setup.  Are you retracting your first comment about this being possible?